# make subversion for online web application using bitbuket

Tags: bitbucket

I have online web application with more than **10 web developer** that work together on that web application, I don't want to install that application in there device, but I want to find away to make these developer work separately on the same application without **make conflict in the code**, I used **bitbucket** to solve that but they require to install the application locally, but for my situation **I don't want to install it in there device** for some reasons. please if any body have idea or tools that lead to solve our situation. thanks.....

Comment: Why don't you want your developers to have a local development copy of the software? It is never a good idea to have developers share a working copy. Can you give each developer their own development server?

Comment: yes I did sub domain for each.